# GROUP BY dd/MM/yyyy in Asp.Net SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, date

I'm trying to group all of my dates together and I'm not able to. At the moment they are saved in the database as a string and will always be in the format dd/MM/yyyy
My statement is

```
SELECT IncDate, SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings GROUP BY IncDate
```

Does any know why I'm not able to group these together? Maybe it's the / in the string? Any help would be greatly appreciated! S

Comment: Very likely the string is not in the exact same format... perhaps you have white space or something. Consider to get all data raw first then group by it using LINQ in the C# code rather than in the SQL command query

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and the results you are getting.  Databases have no problem aggregating by string columns.  Also, storing date/times as strings is a really bad idea (use native types).  But if you must, use ISO standard formats such as YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.

Comment: yeah that actually makes complete sense. Thank you I will give this a go!

Comment: Hi Gordon, I think the issue is simply the white spacing. thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. The problem was simply white lines in my IncDate. So I cleared the database and upon each new date selection I used the String.Empty to make sure the label was completely cleared